# Implicit differentiation question of the second order

Tags: calculus

I’m trying to find $d^2y/dx^2$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ of $3xy-y^2=10$.

I’ve found that $y’=\frac{-3y}{2y+3x}$, but I’m having trouble finding $y’’$ Using implicit differentiation.

Comment: Quotient Rule comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

for the first derivative we get
$$3y+3xy'-2yy'=0$$ or
$$y'=\frac{3y}{2y-3x}$$
and for the second derivative:
$$y''=\frac{3y'(2y-3x)-3y(2y'-3)}{(2y-3x)^2}$$
and here you can plug in $$y'=...$$
and this is equal to $$y''=\frac{18y^2-54xy}{(2y-3x)^3}$$